# ¿Cómo hago un texto editable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, css3

Buenas, estoy creando una página en PHP el cual tiene teorías sobre filosofía y no sé como hago un texto editable, es decir, que un usuario externo a la página como un profesor al ingresar pueda editar el texto directamente en la página, hasta ahora solo sé ingresar texto desde el código con `<p>` pero no directamente desde la página.

Comment: Hola @Andrés. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Un tema es hacer que el usuario pueda editar el texto y otro completamente diferente es que se pueda guardar luego esa edición en una base de datos. Si la intención, es hacer un sistema que permita editar, guardar, eliminar, con permisos de usuarios, etc. quizás es un tema demasiado amplio para hacer en una pregunta. ¿Podrías aclarar la intención? Si es el segundo caso, te recomiendo investigar un poco cómo guardar hacerlo antes de hacer una pregunta puntual. Incluso quizás te sea más sencillo emplear alguna solución de terceros, y no reinventar la rueda.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el atributo `contenteditable` en la etiqueta `p` sin problema:

```css
p {
   color: #222;
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'segoe ui';
   padding: .5rem .8rem;
}
p:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #2980b9;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable>¡Edítame!</p>
```

---

De acuerdo a [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) y [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable), los navegadores que lo soportan son:

**Escritorio**

- Chrome 11+
- Firefox 3.0+
- IE 6+ (lol)
- Opera 10.6+
- Safari 3.2+

**Móvil**

- Navegador Android 3+
- Firefox Mobile 1.0+
- IE Mobile 6+
- Safari Mobile 5+
- Opera Mobile 12.1+

Para `Opera Mini` y `Android Gingerbread` quizás se justifica hacerlo mediante JavaScript. Sin embargo, dudo mucho que haya gente que utilice Opera Mini para algo que no sea ahorrar megas y Android 2.3- (Hasta me cuestionaría si aún se venden esos equipos).

#### Guardar la edición

Para guardar la edición hacemos uso del evento `blur` sobre el elemento editable, asociamos una función que por ejemplo, envíe la edición por AJAX al backend. Para identificar cada elemento editado, se puede agregar un **identificador** para que el servidor sepa **qué elemento** se ha editado:

```
function save(ev) {
  var newValue = ev.target.textContent;
  // enviarlo por AJAX
}
```

---

Ejemplo completo:

```js
function save(ev) {
  let newValue = ev.target.textContent;
  /*const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'guardar-edicion.php');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.readState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 400) {
         // edición exitosa 
      }
      else {
        // problema 
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send({ newValue });
  */
  alert(newValue);
}
```

```css
p {
   color: #222;
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'segoe ui';
   padding: .5rem .8rem;
}
p:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #2980b9;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable onblur="save(event)">¡Edítame!</p>
```

Comment: Bueno... Pero como puedo lograr que me guarde? Con ese código lo hice editable pero no me guarda o no se como lograrlo, o con que código hago que para cuando el usuario de clic en un botón "enviar" automáticamente se guarde

Comment: @AndrésLopezBedoya Lo puedes hacer mediante AJAX, en cuanto se termine de editar, se envía al servidor para que se guarde sin necesidad de recargar la página; es mucho más user-friendly que estar presionando un botón para guardar. Observa mi actualización.

Comment: PD: El código comentado es la petición AJAX, lo comento porque va a dar error en el editor de StackOverflow. Tu debes reemplazar `guardar-edicion.php` por tu fichero o ruta del backend. Además, para saber **qué elemento** ha sido editado, puedes agregar un identificador a cada elemento (`data-id`) para así identificarlos en el servidor.

Comment: Puedes guardarlo en donde quieras en realidad. Especifica qué quieres decir con documento.

Comment: Es que la verdad estoy un poco nuevo con todo esto, disculpa mi ignorancia. Hay forma de guardarlo por ejemplo en un documento .txt o en un <p>, es decir, sin tener que hacer uso de la db.

Comment: La base de datos **solo es necesaria si quieres persistir datos en el tiempo de forma segura**. Nada te exige usar bases de datos. Respecto a tu duda, claro que puedes guardarlo donde quieras. Por ejemplo, si quieres guardarlo en un `p` la variable `newValue` debes asignársela a ese otro `p`: `document.getElementById('otroP').textContent = newValue;`. Si quieres guardarlo en un `archivo`, envía la edición al **servidor** y desde allí **crea el archivo**. Una vez creado lo puedes devolver al usuario para que se descargue.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido mucho

Comment: De nada amigo. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @AndrésLopezBedoya si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor, márcala como aceptada.

Comment: +1 Lastima que la pregunta seguramente será cerrada, y posiblemente se pierda esta excelente respuesta, por ejemplo yo desconocía el atributo contenteditable, seguramente al igual q mucha gente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se hace en ese caso es crear un formulario...Usualmente se juega con los estilos para que al darle click se transforme en una caja de texto....y sea un formulario que se pueda enviar al lado del servidor.